# How to delete headerReferences and footerReferences in Office JS Add-in?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, openxml, word-addins

When i clear the body and sections i expect that the references of Header and Footer will be removed automatically, but unfortunately if i look into file i see the references still persist.

This is how i clear the body and sections...

```
Word.run(async context => {
    context.document.body.clear();
    return context.sync().then(r => {
        const sections = context.document.sections;
        sections.load();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            sections.items.forEach(function (section) {
                // Clear the Body
                section.body.clear();

                // Clear any Headers
                section.getHeader("Primary").clear();
                section.getHeader("FirstPage").clear();
                section.getHeader("EvenPages").clear();

                // Clear any Footers
                section.getFooter("Primary").clear();
                section.getFooter("FirstPage").clear();
                section.getFooter("EvenPages").clear();
            });
        });
    });
}).catch(handleError);
```

This is what i see in .docx file after clearing all items.

```
<w:headerReference r:id='rId9'
                   w:type='even'/>
<w:headerReference r:id='rId10'
                   w:type='default'/>
<w:footerReference r:id='rId11'
                   w:type='even'/>
<w:footerReference r:id='rId12'
                   w:type='default'/>
<w:headerReference r:id='rId13'
                   w:type='first'/>
<w:footerReference r:id='rId14'
                   w:type='first'/>
```

Expected results:

```
<w:headerReference r:id='rId8'
                   w:type='default'/>
<w:footerReference r:id='rId9'
                   w:type='default'/>
```

Is there a way how to delete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now as i understood the unused references can be removed by calling `body.select()` method.

```
Word.run(async context => {
    context.document.body.clear();
    return context.sync().then(r => {
        const sections = context.document.sections;
        sections.load();
        return context.sync().then(function () {
            sections.items.forEach(function (section) {
                // Clear the Body
                section.body.clear();

                // Clear any Headers
                section.getHeader("Primary").clear();
                section.getHeader("FirstPage").clear();
                section.getHeader("EvenPages").clear();

                // Clear any Footers
                section.getFooter("Primary").clear();
                section.getFooter("FirstPage").clear();
                section.getFooter("EvenPages").clear();
            });

            context.document.body.select(); //This line is needed
            
            return context.sync().then(function(){
                console.log("Done");
            });
        });
    });
}).catch(handleError);
```

More about it you can see here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1904